# Why my form action in modal is not update?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with modal form in AngularJs. I have to send different request according to what was entered in the form. I want to change the action url of the form. I want to have a calculate url. When i open the modal my url is not updated in the form action. Why ? What is wrong ?

Here is the code

```
    <script>
      angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
 var url = '/url/test'; // this value is calculated
      var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

          /* Note: The hard coded user object has been commented out, as 
             it is now passed as an object parameter from the HTML template.
          */
          /* $scope.user = {
              user: 'name',
              password: null
          };*/

          $scope.open = function (user) {
              $scope.user = user;
              $modal.open({
                  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                  backdrop: true,
                  windowClass: 'modal',
                  controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, user) {
                      $scope.user = user;
                      $scope.submit = function () {
                          $log.log('Submiting user info.');
                          $log.log(JSON.stringify(user));
                          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                      }
                      $scope.cancel = function () {
                          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                      };
                  },
                  resolve: {
                      user: function () {
                          return $scope.user;
                      }
                  }
              });
          };
      };  
  </script>

  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
          </div>
          <!--HERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE ACTION URL ACCORDING TO THE USER -->
          <form action="{{'/app/'+url}}" ng-submit="submit()">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <label>User name</label>
              <input type="text" ng-model="user.user" />
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn primary-btn" value="Submit" />
            </div>
          </form>
      </script>

      <button class="btn" ng-click="open({user: 'username', password: 'password'})">Open me!</button>
      <div ng-show="user.password">Got back from modal: {{ user | json}}</div>
  </div>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ulOP315xfesjvZ3FXDmP?p=preview) ( Line 57)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have defined your '`url`' in `modelDemoCtrl`

please see working demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/Ddb13hqqrrdCdA5SuRyS?p=preview

**TEMPLATE:**

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
          <p>Your Url: <strong>{{url.user}}</strong></p> 
      </div>
      <!--HERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE ACTION URL ACCORDING TO THE USER -->
      <form action="{{'/app/'+url.user}}" ng-submit="submit()">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <label>User name</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="user.user" />
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn primary-btn" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
  </script>
```

**JS:**

```
 $scope.open = function (user) {
              $scope.user = user;
              $modal.open({
                  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                  backdrop: true,
                  windowClass: 'modal',
                  controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, user) {
                      $scope.user = user;
                      $scope.url = $scope.user;
                      $scope.submit = function () {
                          $log.log('Submiting user info.');
                          $log.log(JSON.stringify(user));
                          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                      }
                      $scope.cancel = function () {
                          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                      };
                  },
                  resolve: {
                      user: function () {
                          return $scope.user;
                      }
                  }
              });
          };
```

Comment: Yes you're right i have to pass user information with "resolve", pass it in the controller and define a $scope.user varibale in my controller and affect user to this variable.Thanks for answering